# Android: PullToRefresh in ListFragment does not refresh the list

Tags: android, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

I am using [Johan Nilssons PullToRefresh library](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) but the code to refresh the list is not executed.

My code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.
    listView = new PullToRefreshListView(getActivity());
    listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            //check if internet connection is available
            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null) {
                Log.d("debug","Keine Internetverbindung, kein Refresh möglich");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Keine Internetverbindung! Refresh nicht möglich!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }else{
                //refresh list
                Log.d("debug","Internetverbindung verfügbar, refreshe Liste");

                DOMParser tmpDOMParser = new DOMParser();
                feed = tmpDOMParser.parseXml("http://www.test.de/feed");

                Log.d("debug", "Refresh Liste mit Feed: "+feed);

                adapter.setNewFeed(feed);
                WriteFeed(feed);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
                listView.onRefreshComplete();
            }
        }
    });

    //inflate the fragment with the custom detail fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_list, null);
    return view;
}
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //new PullToRefresh ListView
    listView = new PullToRefreshListView(getActivity());
    listView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);

    // Set custom list adapter to the ListView        
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), feed);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

My feed_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<mypackage.com.PullToRefreshListView
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

In LogCat the last step is:
Tag: PullToRefreshListView  Text:onRefresh

In my listview the text "Loading" and a spinning symbol shown. Why is the code in `onRefresh()` not executed?

**SOLUTION:**

In my ListFragment I changed the code to:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //inflate the fragment with the custom detail fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_list, null);     
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.
        listView = (PullToRefreshListView) getListView();

        listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                //do refresh stuff here             
        });

        listView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);

        // Set custom list adapter to the ListView        
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), feed);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

My feed_list.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<mypackage.com.PullToRefreshListView
android:id="@id/android:list"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml code for `R.layout.feed_list`?

Comment: You are creating the `ListView` dynamically but not adding it to `Layout` anywhere.`onCreateView` has only this much code?

Comment: I added the request information to the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are creating a new `PullToRefreshListView` instead of using `PullToRefreshListView` in the xml file.

Try this code

```
</LinearLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<mypackage.com.PullToRefreshListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//inflate the fragment with the custom detail fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_list, null);
        // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.
        listView = (PullToRefreshListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                //check if internet connection is available
                ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().
                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null) {
                    Log.d("debug","Keine Internetverbindung, kein Refresh möglich");
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Keine Internetverbindung! Refresh nicht möglich!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }else{
                    //refresh list
                    Log.d("debug","Internetverbindung verfügbar, refreshe Liste");

                    DOMParser tmpDOMParser = new DOMParser();
                    feed = tmpDOMParser.parseXml("http://www.test.de/feed");

                    Log.d("debug", "Refresh Liste mit Feed: "+feed);

                    adapter.setNewFeed(feed);
                    WriteFeed(feed);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
                    listView.onRefreshComplete();
                }
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        listView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);

        // Set custom list adapter to the ListView        
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), feed);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Comment: I implemented it like this but I receive the error `01-10 20:22:56.169: E/AndroidRuntime(9356): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created'` in the code line `listView = (PullToRefreshListView) getListView();`

Comment: Thanks, with your updated code I receive this error: `01-11 06:26:43.260: E/AndroidRuntime(925): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'` in the line `super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);`

Comment: Thanks to your help I could find the solution and added it to my original post! Thank you very much!